# slide div from right to left is not working in my site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is my code

```
$(function() {
  $("#product_content").hide();

  $("#about").on("click", function() {
    $("#home_content").hide();
    $('#product_content').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
  });
});
```

when I click on about it will shows the content.but the sliding effect is not working for me 
I include these  jQuery UIs

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

This is my HTML code.in the menu when i click about us it will load the page but the sliding effect is not working.

```
<div id="wrapper">

     <header>
     <div class="topheader">
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-label="Skip to main navigation" aria-hidden="true" id="open-menu"></i>
        <div id="dd-menu" class="dd-menu level-1" data-button="#open-menu">
           <div class="dd-menu-header">
              <button class="dd-menu-prev">&larr;</button>
              <a class="dd-menu-title logo1"><img src="img/logoh.png"/></a>
              <div class="dd-menu-close"><img class="dd-menu-close" src="images/close.png"></div>
           </div>



           <div class="dd-menu-section"></div>
           <div class="dd-menu-items-container">
              <div class="dd-menu-items open">
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link">
                    <a href="index.html" id="home"> 
                    </i><b>HOME</b></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link" id="about">
                    <a href="#" data-submenu="submenu-one"><b>ABOUT US</b></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link">
                    <a href="#"><b>INFRASTRUCTURE</b></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link">
                    <a href="#" id="product"><b>PRODUCTS</b></a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <a href="product.php">FIBER FLOOR MAT</a>
                          <a href="#">PPF FLOOR MAT</a>
                          <a href="#">JUTE FLOOR MAT</a>
                          <a href="#">RUBBER FLOOR MAT</a>
                          <a href="#">COIR FLOOR MAT</a>
                        </ul>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link">
                    <a href="#"><b>KNOWLEDGE CENTER</b></a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="dd-menu-item link">
                    <a href="#"><b>CONTACT US</b></a>
                 </div>
                  <ul class="clearfix horizontal_list social_icons" style="list-style-type: none;padding-top: 27%;padding-left: 27%;">
                    <li class="facebook m_bottom_5 relative">
                       <span class="tooltip tr_all_hover r_corners color_dark f_size_small">Facebook</span>
                       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="r_corners t_align_c tr_delay_hover f_size_ex_large">
                       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="twitter m_left_5 m_bottom_5 relative">
                       <span class="tooltip tr_all_hover r_corners color_dark f_size_small">Twitter</span>
                       <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="r_corners f_size_ex_large t_align_c tr_delay_hover">
                       <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="google_plus m_left_5 m_bottom_5 relative">
                       <span class="tooltip tr_all_hover r_corners color_dark f_size_small">Twitter</span>
                       <a href="https://plus.google.com/" class="r_corners f_size_ex_large t_align_c tr_delay_hover">
                      <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                       </a>
                    </li>



                 </ul>

              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logoh.png"></a>
        </div>
  </div>

  </header>
  <!-- /header -->

    <div id="home_content">
    <div id="main_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

    <li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-image: url(images/people.jpeg);background-size: cover;background-position: center center; margin-top: 80px;   height: 580px;list-style: none; padding-left: 0%" alt="Cinelli">
   <div class="transparent_1"><h2 class="mycontent content1">OMEGA RUBBER PRODUCTS</h2> 
         <div>
           <p class="sldrcontent">Omega manufactures a complete line of production solutions<br>that meet the strict demands of today's marketplace</br> </p>
        </div>
      <div>
<a class="menu_open"> <button name="button" id="open-menu" class="btt3 btt32 btt-responsive">MORE</button></a>
 </div>  
  </div>
  </li>
   <li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-image: url(images/cinelli-front.jpeg); background-size: cover;background-position: center center;margin-top: 80px;    height: 580px;list-style: none;padding-left: 0%" alt="Cinelli"><div class="transparent_1"><h2 class="mycontent content2">OMEGA FLOOR MATS<span style="color:transparent;">j</span></h2>
  <div>
<p class="sldrcontent">Every step that we take is a step forward based on our Quality Management System</br></p>
  </div>
   <div>
<a class="menu_open"> <button name="button" id="open-menu" class="btt3 btt32 btt-responsive">MORE</button></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </li>
<li class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-image: url(images/surly13.png);background-size: cover;background-position: center center;margin-top: 80px;    height: 580px;list-style: none;padding-left: 0%" alt="Cinelli"><div class="transparent_1"><h2 class="mycontent content3">HIGH-TECH INFRASTRUCTURE</h2> 
 <div>
 <p class="sldrcontent">With great envision Omega quickly adapt the latest technologies and<br> deliver functionally superior products</br></p></div>
   <div>
<a class="menu_open"> <button name="button" id="open-menu" class="btt3 btt32 btt-responsive">MORE</button></a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </li>


</div>
</div>
<div id="product_content">
 <div id="product_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <img src="images/IMG1.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG2.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG3.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG4.jpg">
    <img src="images/IMG5.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: and where's the html code ? also...it seems like everything is working...see here > http://jsfiddle.net/PjSV7/69/  share all relevant code ( html and css ) there might be a problem there

Comment: but it shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: b.easing[this.easing] is not a function"

Comment: problem with jquery UI js... try using latest jquery and jquery ui js. I tried with including the latest js and your code is working!

Comment: include the latest JQUERY . you use an old jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#product_content").hide();
  $("#about").on("click", function() {
    $("#home_content").hide();
    $('#product_content').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 2000);
  });
 });
```

```html
  <html>

   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
 
   <body>
<p id="product_content">By default hidden</p>
  <p id="home_content">home_content</p>
      
      <button id = "about"> about</button> 
  
      <div class = "target">
      </div>
  
   </body>
 
</html>
```

Hope it will help you